# How to paginate a QTableView which has been sent through multiple QSortFilterProxy passes?

Tags: python, pyqt6

In PyQt6 I have a custom QTableView using a model of about 18000 rows, which is passed through several chained custom QSortFilterProxy steps.

I would like to paginate the results and the only method I've found to do this is another QSortFilterProxy based on the row number in the source Model. This works fine with the unfiltered source model but once I put it at the end of the filter chain it starts behaving very badly. Only small portions of the intended results are showing up. My guess is it's filtering based on the sourceModel row number rather than the filtered version of said model.

How do I get it to paginate the filtered results properly? Or get the indexes of the visible rows? Or is there another way to do it that doesn't rely on yet another filter? The user should be able to scroll to first, prev, next, last, or jump to any specific page of their choice.

Sample proxy chain:

```py
self.model = CustomTableModel(dataTable, self.labels)

self.proxyModelA = TextFilterProxy(0)
self.proxyModelA.setSourceModel(self.model)

self.proxyModelB = DictValueProxy(5, "Name")
self.proxyModelB.setSourceModel(self.proxyModelA)

self.paginateProxy = PaginationProxy(maxrows=30)
self.paginateProxy.setSourceModel(self.proxyModelB)

self.tableView.setModel(self.paginateProxy)
```

Current Filter:

```py
class PaginationProxy(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, maxrows=30, parent=None):
        super(PaginationProxy, self).__init__(parent)
        self.maxrows = maxrows

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row_num, parent):
        regex = self.filterRegularExpression()
        pattern = regex.pattern()
        if pattern:
            firstRow = (int(pattern) - 1) * self.maxrows
            lastRow = firstRow + self.maxrows + 1
        else:
            firstRow = 0
            lastRow = self.maxrows + 1
        if row_num in range(firstRow, lastRow):
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: Why are you using a regex (which is based on strings) to define a numerical range? Just set the first row with a custom function, and invalidate the filter.

Comment: Because I don't know how to pass data from view to filter by any means other than setFilterFixedString and setFilterRegularExpression, both of which can only be retrieved within filterAcceptsRow as filterRegularExpression.

Invalidating the filter may be what I need though, thanks.

Comment: Create a get and set of a property and invoke the invalidateFilter method to invoke the filtering method and avoid using regex. On the other hand, do a simple comparison to check if the row should be visible or not to avoid unnecessary use of range

Comment: @eyllanesc If the range object is made persistent, its performance would be almost identical to checking against the minimum and maximum row, due to the way `range` is implemented. I've done some testing with basic classes, and returning `value in self.someRange` is almost as fast as returning `self.start <= value < self.end` (in some cases it's even faster). Using `range` also has the benefit of having a single object to represent the range instead of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Main issues with your attempt

If you want to deal with logical values such as row numbers, using the filter of the proxy is wrong, because it is based on *strings*: it's completely pointless to use a string (even worse, a regex pattern) to represent a number that needs to be used for logical purposes such as this.

The above is also a terrible choice especially if implemented like in your example, because the conversion is done for each call to `filterAcceptsRow()`, meaning that you are doing all the following for ***every single row*** of the source model:

1. get the current filter;
2. get the filter pattern;
3. check if the pattern is valid;
4. eventually convert it to number;
5. compute and create the variables for range values;
6. create a `range()` object;
7. check if the row number is in the range;
8. return the result of the check above;

This is completely ineffective and terribly inefficient, especially for large models (which, coincidentally, is exactly your case).

### Simple page implementation

Instead, you should create a custom function that sets the reference page using actual row numbers; once the reference page is chosen, you only need to create a single `range()` object *just once*, making it as an instance attribute, and finally invalidate the filter.
Then, `filterAcceptsRow()` will just return whether the row number is within that range (`return row_number in self.someRange`).

A simple solution, which can be used for a *static* source model, is to just create a QSortFilterProxyModel subclass that creates the range object for the selected page, and override `filterAcceptsRow()` as explained above. For example:

```py
class SimplePaginationModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, maxRows=50, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.maxRows = max(1, maxRows)
        # the model is empty, the row range is therefore invalid
        self.rowRange = range(0)

    def setCurrentPage(self, page):
        if not self.sourceModel():
            return

        rowCount = self.sourceModel().rowCount()
        if rowCount <= 0:
            firstRow = rangeEnd = 0
        else:
            firstRow = page * self.maxRows

            if firstRow >= rowCount:
                firstRow = (rowCount - 1) // self.maxRows * self.maxRows

            rangeEnd = firstRow + self.maxRows
            if rangeEnd > rowCount:
                rangeEnd = rowCount

        # create the row range just once, as an instance attribute
        self.rowRange = range(firstRow, rangeEnd)

        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):
        # that's it
        return row in self.rowRange

    def setSourceModel(self, model):
        super().setSourceModel(model)
        if model:
            self.setCurrentPage(0)
```

Unfortunately, this does not suffice, because the source model could reduce its *shape* (by filtering) without triggering the filter invalidation of the proxy: the result is that you get less rows than you should, because the row range has not been updated accordingly; despite the issues of your implementation, this is the cause of the problem you mentioned.

That situation is a symptom of a valid optimization.
When rows are removed from the source model, there is no point in going through the whole model in order to filter its contents *again*: all previous contents have been already filtered, so, if the source has removed some rows, it's obviously faster to remove the *related* rows of the proxy.

When that happens, the proxy just removes the related rows, without invalidating the filter, so `filterAcceptsRow()` is not being called and you get only the rows in the previously accepted range that "survived" the filtering of the source. This is obviously problematic for a pagination system, because the row range of the proxy is based on the row count of the source; for example, if a row that is shown in the current page is being removed, then a new row from the next page should probably be shown; if the removed row is before the current page, the last row in the previous page should be inserted, while the last row in the current page should be removed.

This means that a pagination model should always invalidate the filter (and cause `filterAcceptsRow()` calls) whenever the shape of the source model has been filtered, causing rows removal.

A possible workaround is to connect the [`rowsInserted`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsInserted) and [`rowsRemoved`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsRemoved) signals of the source model to `invalidateFilter()`.

```py
class SimplePaginationModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    ...
    def setSourceModel(self, model):
        super().setSourceModel(model)
        if model:
            model.rowsInserted.connect(self.invalidateFilter)
            model.rowsRemoved.connect(self.invalidateFilter)
            self.setCurrentPage(0)
```

This would still be not sufficient, though: if the source is filtered (resulting in less pages), we could end up with an empty model if the previously chosen page was beyond the visible range.

Moreover, we probably want a model that always reflects the amount of available pages reliably, including the possibility to switch to next pages.

### A valid, complete implementation

It's clear that the above pagination may be fine for basic situations, but it won't be enough to cover more complex models, especially when trying to "chain" proxy models, because there's no way to know how any intermediate model (including the actual source at the end of the chain) eventually alters its contents, so we must implement a mechanism that takes into account all changes to the source model of the proxy by connecting to the relevant signals: other than the two mentioned above, we should also consider the [`layoutChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#layoutChanged) and [`modelReset`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#modelReset) signals, but we also should keep track of the previous state of the model *before* the change (to notify about changes to page count or current page number), meaning that we also need to connect to the "about to be" related signals:

- `rowsAboutToBeInserted`
- `rowsAboutToBeRemoved`
- `layoutAboutToBeChanged`
- `modelAboutToBeReset`

These 4 signals can be connected to a simple function that stores the current page count and number, while the related signals (emitted by the model *after* it has changed) are connected to a function that gets the *new* page count and possible current number (possibly decreased if less pages are available), compares them with the previous stored state and eventually emit related signals, but only *after* calling `invalidateFilter()`, so that any change in the proxy would properly reflect the current page count and number.

Once all this is done, the page navigation becomes quite easy, including going to the previous or next page, jumping to the first or last page, and even providing signals that notify when a page (or layout) change causes or prevents the possibility to go backward or forward.

The following is a complete implementation of the above, including an example that shows its behavior:

```py
from random import choice
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class PaginationModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    _currentPage = -1
    currentPageChanged = pyqtSignal(int)
    pageCountChanged = pyqtSignal(int)
    canGoBackChanged = pyqtSignal(bool)
    canGoForwardChanged = pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__(self, maxRows=50, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._maxRows = max(1, maxRows)
        self.rowRange = range(0)

    def _emitCanChange(self, oldBack, oldFwd):
        newBack = self.canGoBack()
        if oldBack != newBack:
            self.canGoBackChanged.emit(newBack)

        newFwd = self.canGoForward()
        if oldFwd != newFwd:
            self.canGoForwardChanged.emit(newFwd)

    def _beginSourceChange(self):
        self._preChangeData = (
            self.pageCount(), 
            self._currentPage, 
            self.canGoBack(), 
            self.canGoForward(), 
        )

    def _endSourceChange(self):
        oldPageCount, oldPage, oldBack, oldFwd = self._preChangeData
        newRowCount = self.sourceModel().rowCount()
        
        if not newRowCount:
            newPageCount = firstRow = rangeEnd = 0
            self._currentPage = -1
        else:
            newPageCount = newRowCount // self._maxRows + 1
            if oldPage < 0:
                self._currentPage = firstRow = 0
            else:
                firstRow = oldPage * self._maxRows

            if firstRow >= newRowCount:
                firstRow = (newRowCount - 1) // self._maxRows * self._maxRows
            rangeEnd = firstRow + self._maxRows
            if rangeEnd > newRowCount:
                rangeEnd = newRowCount
                self._currentPage = newRowCount // self._maxRows

        self.rowRange = range(firstRow, rangeEnd)
        self.invalidateFilter()

        if oldPageCount != newPageCount:
            self.pageCountChanged.emit(newPageCount)

        if oldPage != self._currentPage:
            self.currentPageChanged.emit(self._currentPage)

        self._emitCanChange(oldBack, oldFwd)

    def _setCurrentPage(self, page, force=False):
        if not self.sourceModel():
            return

        rowCount = self.sourceModel().rowCount()
        if rowCount <= 0:
            firstRow = rangeEnd = 0
        else:
            firstRow = page * self._maxRows

            if firstRow >= rowCount:
                firstRow = (rowCount - 1) // self._maxRows * self._maxRows
            rangeEnd = firstRow + self._maxRows
            if rangeEnd > rowCount:
                rangeEnd = rowCount

        self.rowRange = range(firstRow, rangeEnd)

        newPage = firstRow // self._maxRows
        if self._currentPage != newPage or force:
            oldBack = self.canGoBack()
            oldFwd = self.canGoForward()
            self._currentPage = newPage
            self.invalidateFilter()
            self.currentPageChanged.emit(newPage)
            self._emitCanChange(oldBack, oldFwd)

    def maxRows(self):
        return self._maxRows

    def setMaxRows(self, maxRows):
        if maxRows <= 0 or self._maxRows == maxRows:
            return
        if not self.sourceModel():
            self._maxRows = maxRows
            return

        oldPageCount = self.pageCount()
        oldBack = self.canGoBack()
        oldFwd = self.canGoForward()

        self._maxRows = maxRows

        self.invalidateFilter()
        self._setCurrentPage(max(0, self._currentPage), True)

        newPageCount = self.pageCount()
        if oldPageCount != newPageCount:
            self.pageCountChanged.emit(newPageCount)
            self._emitCanChange(oldBack, oldFwd)

    def canGoBack(self):
        return self._currentPage > 0

    def canGoForward(self):
        return self._currentPage < self.pageCount() - 1

    def firstPage(self):
        self.setCurrentPage(0)

    def previousPage(self):
        self.setCurrentPage(self._currentPage - 1)

    def nextPage(self):
        self.setCurrentPage(self._currentPage + 1)

    def lastPage(self):
        self.setCurrentPage(self.sourceModel().rowCount() // self._maxRows)

    def pageCount(self):
        if self.sourceModel():
            pages, rest = divmod(self.sourceModel().rowCount(), self._maxRows)
            if rest:
                pages += 1
            return pages
        return 0

    def currentPage(self):
        return self._currentPage

    def setCurrentPage(self, page):
        if self.sourceModel() and page >= 0 and self._currentPage != page:
            self._setCurrentPage(page)

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):
        return row in self.rowRange

    def setSourceModel(self, model):
        old = self.sourceModel()
        if old == model:
            return

        if old:
            old.rowsAboutToBeRemoved.disconnect(self._beginSourceChange)
            old.rowsAboutToBeInserted.disconnect(self._beginSourceChange)
            old.layoutAboutToBeChanged.disconnect(self._beginSourceChange)
            old.modelAboutToBeReset.disconnect(self._beginSourceChange)
            old.rowsRemoved.disconnect(self._endSourceChange)
            old.rowsInserted.disconnect(self._endSourceChange)
            old.layoutChanged.disconnect(self._endSourceChange)
            old.modelReset.disconnect(self._endSourceChange)
            self._currentPage = -1

        super().setSourceModel(model)

        if not model:
            self.rowRange = range(0)
        else:
            model.rowsAboutToBeRemoved.connect(self._beginSourceChange)
            model.rowsAboutToBeInserted.connect(self._beginSourceChange)
            model.layoutAboutToBeChanged.connect(self._beginSourceChange)
            model.modelAboutToBeReset.connect(self._beginSourceChange)
            model.rowsRemoved.connect(self._endSourceChange)
            model.rowsInserted.connect(self._endSourceChange)
            model.layoutChanged.connect(self._endSourceChange)
            model.modelReset.connect(self._endSourceChange)

            self._setCurrentPage(max(0, self._currentPage))


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, rowCount=2000):
        super().__init__()

        self.sourceModel = QStandardItemModel(rowCount, 1)
        letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
        for i in range(rowCount):
            self.sourceModel.setItem(i, 0, QStandardItem(
                ''.join(choice(letters) for _ in range(8))))

        table = QTableView()
        table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        table.horizontalHeader().hide()

        self.filterModel = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.filterModel.setSourceModel(self.sourceModel)
        self.pageModel = PaginationModel()
        self.pageModel.setSourceModel(self.filterModel)

        table.setModel(self.pageModel)

        textFilterEdit = QLineEdit()
        topLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        topLayout.addWidget(QLabel('Filter:'))
        topLayout.addWidget(textFilterEdit)
        topLayout.addWidget(QLabel('Max rows:'))
        maxRowSpin = QSpinBox(
            minimum=1, maximum=self.sourceModel.rowCount(), singleStep=5)
        maxRowSpin.setValue(self.pageModel.maxRows())
        topLayout.addWidget(maxRowSpin)

        self.firstBtn = QToolButton(text='First')
        self.prevBtn = QToolButton(text='Prev')
        self.pageSpin = QSpinBox(minimum=1)
        self.nextBtn = QToolButton(text='Next')
        self.lastBtn = QToolButton(text='Last')
        pageLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        pageLayout.addWidget(self.firstBtn)
        pageLayout.addWidget(self.prevBtn)
        pageLayout.addWidget(self.pageSpin)
        pageLayout.addWidget(self.nextBtn)
        pageLayout.addWidget(self.lastBtn)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addLayout(topLayout)
        layout.addLayout(pageLayout)
        layout.addWidget(table)

        self.pageSpin.setMaximum(self.pageModel.pageCount())
        self.pageSpin.setSuffix('/{}'.format(self.pageModel.pageCount()))

        textFilterEdit.textEdited.connect(self.filterModel.setFilterWildcard)
        maxRowSpin.valueChanged.connect(self.pageModel.setMaxRows)

        self.firstBtn.clicked.connect(self.pageModel.firstPage)
        self.prevBtn.clicked.connect(self.pageModel.previousPage)
        self.nextBtn.clicked.connect(self.pageModel.nextPage)
        self.lastBtn.clicked.connect(self.pageModel.lastPage)
        self.pageSpin.valueChanged.connect(
            lambda p: self.pageModel.setCurrentPage(p - 1))

        self.pageModel.currentPageChanged.connect(self.currentPageChanged)
        self.pageModel.pageCountChanged.connect(self.pageCountChanged)
        self.pageModel.canGoBackChanged.connect(self.updateButtons)
        self.pageModel.canGoForwardChanged.connect(self.updateButtons)

        self.updateButtons()

    def currentPageChanged(self, page):
        with QSignalBlocker(self.pageSpin):
            self.pageSpin.setValue(page + 1)

    def pageCountChanged(self, count):
        with QSignalBlocker(self.pageSpin):
            self.pageSpin.setMaximum(count)
            if count:
                self.pageSpin.setMinimum(1)
        self.pageSpin.setSuffix('/{}'.format(count))

    def updateButtons(self):
        canBack = self.pageModel.canGoBack()
        self.firstBtn.setEnabled(canBack)
        self.prevBtn.setEnabled(canBack)
        canFwd = self.pageModel.canGoForward()
        self.nextBtn.setEnabled(canFwd)
        self.lastBtn.setEnabled(canFwd)


app = QApplication([])
main_window = Example()
main_window.show()
app.exec()
```

### Further notes

The above signal connections show how important to follow the appropriate implementation in its order: correctly call model functions and emit all their required signals, respecting the logical context of any change.

This is extremely important when implementing custom models, as a common mistake is to just emit the "final" (or wrong) signals whenever the contents of the model change.

For instance, many sources often suggest to just emit `layoutChanged` when rows or columns have been added or removed, but that is wrong in principle (and is often cause of crash when the custom model is used on a proxy).
Such changes must **always** be done in the proper order, with both the related signal pairs: for instance, a row insertion should always be preceded by a correct `rowsAboutToBeInserted` signal (*before* the actual insertion) and followed by `rowsInserted` one after all changes have been applied.

In reality, the existing functions of QAbstractItemModel should always be preferred in such cases; for example, `beginInsertRows()` and `endInsertRows()` for the case above.

As usual, going through the documentation is mandatory, starting from the official [Qt Model/View Programming](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html) guide.

Comment: Wow what an extensive reply! Will take me a bit to dig through it, but for now, thank you very much!

Comment: Follow up: How would I subsequently sort the entire table once paginated? Sorting after pagination is quite logically only sorting the visible chunk. Is there a way to force the sort of the Pagination proxy to target the source model instead of the results?

Comment: I'm just about to implement something like this, and this is brilliant. Much better than what I was thinking I had to do. In reply to Onion Ninja, apply the sort wherever you want. If the pagination proxy is implemented correctly, it will stay on the same page, and the data on that page will update as appropriate for the new sort.